# Propagation rules for the cross-resonance gate of IBM ($R_{zx}$)

Tags: quantum-gate, pauli-gates, noise

The [$R_{zx}$](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RZXGate.html) is the fundamental two-qubit gate supported by IBM processors. I'd like to see how Pauli operators propagate over such a gate.

Other well-known cases are shown in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all unitaries $U$ and $V$, we have
$$
UV=V'U\iff V'=UVU^\dagger.\tag1
$$
Thus, in order to find $V'$ into which $V$ turns as we propagate $U$ over it all we need to do is conjugate $V$ by $U$. For example, calculation shows that
$$
\text{CNOT}\circ(X\otimes I)\circ\text{CNOT}^\dagger = X\otimes X\tag2
$$
in agreement with the first circuit equality.

In general $R_{ZX}(\theta)=\exp\left(-i\frac{\theta}{2}Z\otimes X\right)$ is an infinite gate family, so almost all of them are non-Cliffords. Consequently, $V'$ won't generally be a Pauli operator even if $V$ is.

However, if $\theta\in\{0,\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\}$ then $R_{ZX}(\theta)$ is Clifford. The cases $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$ are trivial. If $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ there are two possibilities. If Pauli operator $P$ commutes with $Z\otimes X$ then
$$
\begin{align}
P'&=R_{ZX}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)P R_{ZX}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^\dagger\\
&=PR_{ZX}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)R_{ZX}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^\dagger=P.\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Otherwise,
$$
\begin{align}
P'&=R_{ZX}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)P R_{ZX}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^\dagger\\
&=PR_{ZX}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^\dagger R_{ZX}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^\dagger\equiv P\circ(Z\otimes X)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
where $\equiv$ denotes equality up to unobservable global phase.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I implicitly refered to the maximally entangling case: $\theta = \pi/2$. I edit the question.

Comment: As a rule, you shouldn't edit questions in a way that changes their meaning after an answer is posted. In this case, your original question is actually more general and includes the edit as a simple special case, so I see no benefit to the edit and took the liberty to roll it back. Hope you don't mind. The present question is genuinely better. I also edited my answer to discuss the case $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ explicitly.